# Whiteboard Problem, my array is remaining sorted in solution

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mapping, constants

The whiteboard problem is: find shortest string in an array and then shorten all of the other strings to that length starting at `index 0`

I use sorting to find the shortest string. (not best practice but hey i'm learning). But when I try to map the `arr` later, it remains sorted, even if I set it to a different variable early in the function. Is this an issue with `let`? should I be using `const` instead?

my `unsorted.map` is returning a sorted array. I have no idea why.

Here is my solution:

```
function cutIt(arr){
    let unsorted = arr;
    console.log(unsorted)
    
    let sortedArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
    let shortest = sortedArr[0].length;
    
    console.log(unsorted)
    
    return unsorted.map(str => str.slice(0, shortest))
}
```

Comment: You can look at ways of cloning the array before sorting it.  But perhaps easier would be to `map` over it to get the lengths of the strings, and call `Math.min(...lengths)` to get your `shortest` value, and proceed with your final `map`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: The answer there will solve the problem, yes, but there are better solutions to the underlying problem.

Comment: @ScottSauyet OP didn't ask for a better solution. OP asked why the "copy" of his array get sorted too, hence it's a duplicate

Comment: This totally makes sense. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

As the comments pointed out, you can look to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085) to display ways of making shallow or deep copies of an array.

But you noted that your sort is not the best way to find the minimum length.  This version is simpler, to my mind.  We use `map` to get the string lengths and then `Math.min` to take the smallest one.  Then we `map` the array as you did in your first answer.  The code ends up much simpler:

```js
const cutIt = (arr) => {
  const shortest = Math .min (...arr .map (s => s .length))
  return arr .map (s => s .slice (0, shortest))
}

console .log (
  cutIt (['disappointed', 'joyous', 'happy', 'sad', 'upset'])
)
```

Comment: This question and your answer are [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398720/is-a-question-still-a-duplicate-if-there-are-better-ways-to-solve-the-underlying)

Comment: @Machavity: Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. it makes a copy of input array

```
let sortedArr = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
```